# JSON en android (Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

```
<?php

/** ESTA ES MI Database.php
 * Clase que envuelve una instancia de la clase PDO
 * para el manejo de la base de datos
 */
require_once 'mysql_login.php';
class Database
{
    /**
     * Única instancia de la clase
     */
    private static $db = null;
    /**
     * Instancia de PDO
     */
    private static $pdo;
    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // Crear nueva conexión PDO
            self::getDb();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Manejo de excepciones
        }
    }
    /**
     * Retorna en la única instancia de la clase
     * @return Database|null
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
    /**
     * Crear una nueva conexión PDO basada
     * en los datos de conexión
     * @return PDO Objeto PDO
     */
    public function getDb()
    {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE .
                ';host=' . HOSTNAME .
                ';port:3306;', // Eliminar este elemento si se usa una instalación por defecto
                USERNAME,
                PASSWORD,
////// no se si la codificcion de aqui esta bien o como deberia ser lo e "UTF8"
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );
            // Habilitar excepciones
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    }
    /**
     * Evita la clonación del objeto
     */
    final protected function __clone()
    {
    }
    function _destructor()
    {
        self::$pdo = null;
    }
}
?>

<?php
/** archivo Detalle_Encuesta.php
 * Representa la estructura de los Detalles_Encuestas
 * almacenadas en la base de datos
 */
require 'Database.php';
class Encuesta
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Retorna en la fila especificada de la tabla 'Alumnos'
     *
     * @param $idEncuesta Identificador del registro
     * @return array Datos del registro
     */
    public static function getAll()
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Detalle_Encuesta";
        try {
            // Preparar sentencia
            $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
            // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
            $comando->execute();
            return $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>

?php
/** ESTE ES MI ARCHIVO obtener_detalle.php de aqui es donde obtengo en JSON
 * Obtiene todos lose Detalles_Encuesta de la base de datos
 */
require 'Detalle_Encuesta.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    // Manejar petición GET
    $detalle = Encuesta::getAll(); //La variable 'detalle' es independiente de la variabale 
    if ($detalle) {
       // $datos["estado"] = 1;
        $datos["Detalles"] = $detalle;
        print json_encode($datos);

    } else {
        print json_encode(array(
            "estado" => 2,
            "mensaje" => "Ha ocurrido un error"
        ));
    }
}

?>

//CODIGO EN ANDROID EDITADO DE ACUERDO A COMENTARIO
if(params[1].equals("1")){    // Consulta de todos los detalles de la encuesta
                System.out.println("entramos al primer if ");
                try {
                    url = new URL(cadena);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                            " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                    //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                    int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        System.out.println("1 entramos al segun if ");

                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                       // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                        // EDITADO PERO NI HACE ME DEJA PASARLO A ONBJETO json 
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));

                        System.out.println("2 Pasamos del Bufferader ");

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            buffer.append(line);
                        }
                        //Muestro lo que hay en la variable buffer y efectivamente en un objeto JSON
                        System.out.println("3 Pasamos el ciclo while y muestro lo que contiene el Json obtenido"+ buffer);

                        // Aqui trato de convertir el String a objeto JSON --Y DE AQUI NO PASA TRUENA Y LANZA LA EXCEPCION--

                        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString()); // -- EDITADO
                        // LA LINEA DE ARRIBA LA PROBE DE ESTA FORMA  --> JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer); Y MARCO ERROR AL COMPILAR 


                        // ---- AQUI YA NI ENTRA ---
                        System.out.println(" 5 Esto hay en la variable : " + parentObject);

                        JSONArray parentArray =parentObject.getJSONArray("Detalles");

                        System.out.println("Estoy hay en la variable paretArray: " + parentArray);

                       final StringBuffer   finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
                            // hay alumnos a mostrar

                            for(int i=0;i<parentArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                               // --- GRACIAS A QUIEN ME HIZO VER MI ERROR EN ESTAS LINEAS
                                String iddetalle = finalObject.getString("idDetalle_Encuesta");
                                String promo = finalObject.getString("Nom_Promotor"); //-- EDITADO
                                String jefe = finalObject.getString("Nom_Jefebrigada");// -- EDITADP
                                String cordi = finalObject.getString("Nom_Coordinador");
                                finalBufferedData.append(iddetalle + " " + promo + " " + jefe + cordi + "\n");

                                                       }
                                 devuelve = finalBufferedData.toString();
                              }



                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("fallo en el primer try");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("fallo en el segundo try");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("fallo en el tercer try");
                }


                return devuelve;

            }
```

Aquí muestro los mensajes por pantalla donde falla la App:

> System.err: org.json.JSONException:
>   Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   08-09 01:33:25.614 32730-493/silver.serviceweb W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 08-09 01:33:25.614
>   32730-493/silver.serviceweb W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160) 08-09 01:33:25.614
>   32730-493/silver.serviceweb W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)

y les dejo mi JSON y su estructura

```
{
    "Detalles": [{
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "1",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Juan",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Luis",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Maria"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "13",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Silverio",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Gustavo",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Carlos"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "15",
        "Nom_Promotor": "yo",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "yo",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "yoyo"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "16",
        "Nom_Promotor": "test",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "test",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "tst"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "1ISBUL78QB",
        "Nom_Promotor": "tregreg",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "rgerg",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "rgerg"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "1U41OZQTA6",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "PENELOPE",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "de la rosa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "2",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Fernando",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Martin",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Luis"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "3",
        "Nom_Promotor": "test",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "test",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "test"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "4",
        "Nom_Promotor": "test",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "test",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "test"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "5NU1EYRB5K",
        "Nom_Promotor": "GREGORIO",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "PENELOPE",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "PANCHA"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "7NMYF3XLD7",
        "Nom_Promotor": "tes",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "tes",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "tes"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "857MZL85O0",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "PENELOPE",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "de la rosa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "860R2JFYXV",
        "Nom_Promotor": "asa",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "aasa",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "asa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "9",
        "Nom_Promotor": "test",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "test",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "test"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "96BVZ0XJL2",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "de la rosa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "BH8GU5H4N9",
        "Nom_Promotor": "tes",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "tes",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "tes"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "CIQSBG38ZI",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Leticia Najera De La Rosa",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "PENELOPE",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "D6OW6T2VDS",
        "Nom_Promotor": "pepe",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "sancho",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "juan"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "DUM1GOWC85",
        "Nom_Promotor": "pepe",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "sancho",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "juan"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "GQS20MPC94",
        "Nom_Promotor": "tregreg",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "IZ3YT37JAT",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "KTBOKS0QUS",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "ONJ7QSS6WI",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "OVOSOQHINW",
        "Nom_Promotor": "gverfve",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "trtrtr",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "rgerg"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "PGQSY8TOKD",
        "Nom_Promotor": "pepe",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "sancho",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "juan"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "SM5KLCA7S7",
        "Nom_Promotor": "pepe",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "sancho",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "juan"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "W2A5S36KJ3",
        "Nom_Promotor": "asa",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "aasa",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "asa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "XPG6SNQQRT",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Oscar",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "Emiliano",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "de la rosa"
    }, {
        "idDetalle_Encuesta": "Z74YJSBTZX",
        "Nom_Promotor": "Leticia Najera De La Rosa",
        "Nom_Jefebrigada": "PENELOPE",
        "Nom_Coordinador": "Lara"
    }]
}
```

Cabe mencionar que ya validé el JSON y está bien, el detalle es ¿por qué no lo puedo pasar a objeto JSON?

Comment: No me deja editarte el mensaje. Colo ca todo el código en forma de código porfa, asi la verdad es que se ve bastante mal para entender. O que alguien lo haga :P

Comment: @carlossilverio, la razón de "JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject " es causado exclusivamente porque lo que intentas procesar como JSONObject en realidad no lo es , imprime buffer.toString() y comenta que se obtiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, el error que describes en tu pregunta:

> org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

**es causado porque lo que intentas procesar como JSONObject en realidad no lo es.**

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
```

**Revisa cuidadosamente que contiene `buffer.toString()` ya que definitivamente no es un objeto Json.**

---

Además tienes otros detalles, primeramente, no puedes usar `getString()` para  `idDetalle_Encuesta` y que tiene valores alfanuméricos. También los key tienen nombres incorrectos , recuerda que son case-sensitive, debe ser Nom_Promotor y no Nom_promotor, Nom_Jefebrigada y no Nom_jefebrigada, agrego el ajuste:

```
    String iddetalle = finalObject.getString("idDetalle_Encuesta"); //NO finalObject.getInt("idDetalle_Encuesta");
    String promo = finalObject.getString("Nom_Promotor");//NO "Nom_promotor";
    String jefe = finalObject.getString("Nom_Jefebrigada");// NO "Nom_jefebrigada";
    String cordi = finalObject.getString("Nom_Coordinador");
```

---

**Actualización:**

La respuesta en realidad obtenía un contenido json pero no era "valido" ya que al inicio tiene uno o varios caracteres ASCII no imprimibles, que se representan como espacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso **una solución es remover esos caracteres ASCII que no son imprimibles pero impiden tu respuesta sea procesada con un verdadero json**, usa el método que sugiero para eliminar esta información no necesaria:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", ""));
```

Comment: String JSON= buffer.toString();

                        //Muestro lo que hay en la variable JSON y efectivamente en un objeto JSON
                        System.out.println("3 Pasamos el ciclo while y muestro lo que contiene el Json obtenido"+ JSON);   y me devuelve un JSON

Comment: He agregado una solución al problema, en realidad te recomiendo también revisar el .php que genera el .json, saludos!

Comment: Solucionado,Eres un crack llevaba noches tratando de resolver esto, como es que te diste cuenta de esos caracteres no visibles? Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Es un placer, espero en un futuro tu ayudes a otros desarrolladores, aquí hay muchos usuarios que pueden ayudarte en cualquier tecnologia, solo recuerda estructurar correctamente tu pregunta. La razón del error es que el json no podia procesarse como tal, te recomiendo 2 cosas importantes debugging y puedes hacer uso del Log para imprimir valores, en este caso después de la palabra "obtenido" no existía espacio pero aparecía en la impresión del valor, incluso revisando directamente el valor de la variable.   Saludos! =)

Comment: Claro que si tomare en cuenta tus consejos y de igual forma espero ayudar a otros desarrolladores, saludos y te deseo el mejor de los éxitos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a modificar la codificacion del Buffer a `UTF-8` así `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,'UTF-8'));`. Es posible que al recibir el fichero, por la codificación del servidor y la tuya, se incluyan caracteres que no ves, pero que hacen que sea un `JSON` invalido para el constructor.

Ademas te recomiendo cambiar `StringBuffer` a `StringBuilder`, a no ser que te encuentres en un ambiente multi-hilo, `StringBuilder` será mas rápido.

¿El recurso al que consultas para recibir el `JSON` es tuyo? ¿De ser así, tienes puesta la codificación en `UTF-8`?

Comment: he seguido tu consejo y nada me lanza la misma excepcion edite mi pregunta y coloque mis archivos php de donde genero el JSON no se si ahi este el error, es raro porque si obtengo el JSON pero a la hora de convertirlo a Objeto truena.